# Twitter share button custom

Tags: twitter

How to change the twitter share button image

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false"`>
```

This is my code

Answer (score 0):

There is a helpful article from [Medium](https://medium.com/@carolynmcneillie/how-to-embed-an-image-in-a-custom-click-to-tweet-link-5d3631eec790). In it, the author simply uses a Font Awesome icon and some CSS to create her own Twitter share button. Here is the code from her button.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Discover%20your%20aura%20at%20http://www.carolynmcneillie.com/colours%20pic.twitter.com/xTreZlYNJh%20@carolynalive"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
```

Is this what you were looking for? Or did you mean that you wanted to change the image that goes along with the tweet?